# Make a text within a div selectable

Tags: javascript, css

To make a div unselectable

```
<div id='test'>Cannot Select this</div>

#test {
   -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

is used.

Is there a way to make a div selectable in case it is already unselectable, without actually removing the unselectable property. Something that forces select.

Comment: Did you try using classes with javascirpt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use classes to apply behavior/styles that are to be added/removed dynamically:

```
<div id="test" class="unselectable">Cannot Select this</div>

.unselectable{
   -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

And in your script:

```
$('#test').addClass('unselectable');
```

Or

```
$('#test').removeClass('unselectable');
```

Answer (score 2):

Put `-webkit-user-select: initial` on the child element.

Here's a working **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7APfD/)**.

```css
.outer {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

.inner {
  -webkit-user-select: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  Unselectable

  <div class="inner">
    Selectable
  </div>

  Unselectable
</div>
```